# OpenFDA NDC endpoint has multiple RXCUI values for a single product NDC

Tags: openfda

I'm currently operating under the assumption that any two NDCs with the same RxCUI value are pharmaceutical equivalents. Hopefully that's correct.

When querying the NDC data from OpenFDA, I noticed that for any given product NDC, there can be multiple RxCUI values. My understanding of the RxCUI value is very limited, but I would like to get a one-to-one relationship for RxCUI to package NDC. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your assumption about pharmaceutical equivalency is correct.

The relationship between RxCUI and Package NDC is actually many-to-many. For example, [this](https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=openfda.spl_set_id.exact:b024ab38-e5da-4f5a-888f-e2a281578290) cold & flu relief drug has multiple rxcui values -- 1086991,          1110988, 1801964 -- and these rxcui values correspond to other NDC drugs, too ([here is](https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=openfda.spl_set_id.exact:23f5b5d4-930a-4968-b09d-fa88567a12cd) an example). So I am not sure building a one-to-one relationship would be reasonable.

Comment: Am I not understanding [this paragraph](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/rxnorm/docs/techdoc.html#anch_68) (section 7.0) correctly? "...a single NDC code should properly be associated with only a single RxCUI, though a single RxCUI can have multiple NDCs...". Also, as an example, in OpenFDA, NDC 50102-300-13 has three RxCUI values, but in RXNSAT.RRF, it only has the last of the three values. Is it possible that the last value is the only one that's still currently relevant, and perhaps the ones before that are historical and now retired?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not understanding why multiple RxCUIs are being returned for a single NDC. It was my understanding that a single NDC code would only be associated with a single RxCUI, but an RxCUI could be associated with multiple NDCs. I don't have enough points to comment on the thread, but wanted to know if the original poster ever figured this out.

Comment: Nope, never figured it out. Other priorities came up and we never got a good solution for this. Sorry!